# Regarding supremum of Mobius distance

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be compact Hausdorff space in $\mathbb{C^n}$. Let $w_1, w_2 \in K$. $C(K)$ be the space of all continuous maps on $K$. Lets define $c(w_1, w_2)$, as follows. Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc in
$\mathbb{C}.$

$c(w_1, w_2)= \sup_f\left\{\left|\frac{f(w_1)-f(w_2)}{1-\overline{f(w_2)}f(w_1)}\right| : f\in A(\mathbb{D})\right\}$, where $A(\mathbb{D})= \{ f\in C(K) : f(K)\subset \mathbb{D}\}$.

Is it true that $c(w_1,w_2)=1$ for any $w_1\neq w_2$?

Comment: You meant $c(w_1,w_2,f)< 1$ and $\sup_f c(w_1,w_2,f)=1$

Comment: Yes. The supremum is taken over all such f’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lemma 1**.  If $a,z\in \mathbb D$, then
$$
  \left|{a-z\over 1-\bar a z}\right| \leq 1.
  $$

*Proof*.  Consider the holomorphic function $f$   defined  on $\overline{\mathbb D}$ by
$$
  f(z)  =  {a-z\over 1-\bar a z}.
  $$
For $|z|=1$, notice that
$$
  |f(z)|  = {1\over |\bar  z|}  |f(z)| =
  {1\over |\bar  z|}  \left|{a-z\over 1-\bar a z}\right| =
  \left|{a-z\over \bar z-\bar a }\right| = 1.
  $$
The conclusion then follows from the  maximum modulus principle.  QED

---

This said, one sees that $c(w_1, w_2)\leq 1$.  Next, given any $\varepsilon$ with $0<\varepsilon <1$,  use Uryshon to produce a continuous function
$$
  f:K\to[0,1-\varepsilon ],
  $$
such that $f(w_1)=1-\varepsilon $, and  $f(w_2)=0$.  Then $f$ lies in $A(\mathbb D)$, and
$$
  \frac{f(w_1)-f(w_2)}{1-\overline{f(w_2)}f(w_1)} = 1-\varepsilon ,
  $$
so we conclude that in fact $c(w_1, w_2)=1$.

Comment: Ok. If I take $K$ to be the closed unit disc $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. And in the definition of $A(\mathbb{D})$, instead of $C(K)$, I take the space of all functions analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ (basically the Disc algebra), then will $c(w_1, w_2)$ be one?

Comment: Would you like to spell out your new question in detail?  I am a bit confused because of the way in which functions in A(D), whose range are not necessarily contained in the disk, are now being composed with the Blaschke factor.