# Regarding supremum of Mobius distance with function values from the Disc algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc in
$\mathbb{C}.$

Let $w_1, w_2 \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with $w_1\neq w_2.$

Let $\tilde{c}(w_1, w_2)= \sup_f\left\{\left|\frac{f(w_1)-f(w_2)}{1-\overline{f(w_2)}f(w_1)}\right| : f\in \tilde{A}(\mathbb{D})\right\}$, where

$\tilde{A}(\mathbb{D})= \{ f\in$ Disc algebra$ : f(\overline{\mathbb{D}})\subset \mathbb{D}\}$.

Where the disc Algebra is the space of all complex valued functions that are analytic on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and are continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}.$ Is it true that  $\tilde{c}(w_1, w_2)$ is always strictly less than 1?

This question is similar to [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865324/regarding-supremum-of-mobius-distance). The difference is that in the previous question the supremum was taken over bounded *continuous* functions, but here the supremum is taken over bounded *analytic* functions.

Comment: This looks related to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865324/42969. Perhaps you can point out where the difference is, and why the supremum should be $< 1$ in one case and $=1$ in the other case.

Comment: @MartinR I have made an edit pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem) states that
$$
\left |\frac{f(w_1) - f(w_2)}{1 - \overline{f(w_2)} f(w_1)} \right| \le \left |\frac{w_1 - w_2}{1 - \overline{w_2} w_1} \right|
$$
for all holomorphic functions $f: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$. It follows that
$$
\tilde{c}(w_1, w_2) \le \left |\frac{w_1 - w_2}{1 - \overline{w_2} w_1} \right| < 1 \, .
$$